# Unix server - Windows client, connection failed

Tags: c++, c, sockets, client-server, winsock

Is there anything more required in order to communicate a server unix process and a client windows process? After compiling both, i run server and then i run client. However, client fails at connect() with error: 10061.

client (windows application):

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib.
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int wmain()
{

    // Initialize Winsock.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("WSAStartup() failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a socket for connecting to server.
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket() failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
    sockaddr_in Service;
    memset(&Service, 0, sizeof(Service));
    Service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    Service.sin_port = htons(27015);

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *) &Service, sizeof (Service));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("connect() failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            printf("closesocket() failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Message that has to be sent.
    char message[1000];

    printf("\nEnter message: ");
    gets_s(message);

    printf("Message you wrote is: %s\n", message);

    // Send a message.
    if (send(ConnectSocket, message, sizeof(message), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("send() failed with error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    printf("Message successfully sent to server.");

closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

while(1);

return 0;
}
```

server (unix application):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <gnu/stubs-64.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int n;
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char sendBuff[1025];

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(27015); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

        n = read(connfd,sendBuff,255);
        printf("Here is the message: %s\n",sendBuff);

        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
     }
}
```

Client is running on Windows 7, while server on Fedora 19 (VMware). The port was ok when i run client-server windows applications. Also, I have no anti-virus SW installed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are connecting to 127.0.0.1, aka localhost, aka the address of the machine you are running on. That can't possibly be the correct IP address for the remote host - even one running in a virtual machine on the same physical hardware.

Comment: You are talking about a server and a client, with different operating systems. So I assume these two are different machines. Then 127.0.0.1 cannot be used to connect from one machine to the other, as 127.0.0.1 always means localhost, that is the machine itself. On your Windows machines, it's the Windows machine, on your Linux machine, it's your Linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a connection refused error because the client is connecting to the client machine, not to the server machine.

In the client code, replace the address 127.0.0.1 with the server's address.

Comment: Also, the server code should be listening on 0.0.0.0 (any address), or the machine's IP address.

Comment: It looks like it's already doing that, @LaszloValko: `serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY)`

Comment: oh, yes, my eyes are not what they used to be... :)

Comment: Ι put 192.168.32.130 that ifconfig returned, in the field inet. Now, I get no error but neither the prompt "Enter message: " appears and the application closes a short time later. What am I missing?

Comment: The `gets_s` function takes two parameters. You are passing only one, so the program is probably crashing there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5x9wc7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I get again error 10061. I suppose that the destination IP address is not correct, but I can't figure out what IP address should I include.

Comment: How have you configured the networking for the vm, do you use bridged mode or what? Does the server have a static IP address or is it assigned by DHCP?

Comment: I found that VMware Bridge Protocol is missing and trying to install it, I get the error: the specified service has been marked for deletion. I don't know if this affects. If so, I'm thinking of using Cygwin.

Comment: You might get better help for that problem from http://superuser.com (I've never used VMWare)